# Change style of Bootstrap listgroup active item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to style an active item in bootstrap list-group similar to this:

[image]

See how Recent is highlighted with just a dark border on the left.

This is my code:

[Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ugqxte?file=src%2FApp.js)

This is my css:

```
.list-group-item.active {
  background-size: 10px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
  border-color: #add8e6;
}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Added a border-left: 5px solid blue and it worked